# Does parameterized query remove reserved keyword and symbols

Tags: c#, wpf, parameterized-query, sql-server-2016-express

If so, if my varchar contains ; or [ or the keyward "Create" that will get automatically deleted? I don't think that was this simple, what is the mechanism of parameterization to avoid sql injection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't *remove* any characters.  Rather, it treats those characters *as values* rather than as code.  If you pass in a string with a semicolon or a quote mark or any other meaningful character/keyword then you'll simply end up with a string value that has that semicolon or quote mark or keyword in it.

If you construct the query as a raw string, rather than using a parameterized query, then you need to ensure that the characters are appropriately escaped in order to have the same behavior, and that's a non-trivial task (if you want to support every possibility) which is why parameterized queries exist to handle it for you.